# $x_n \sim \frac n{\log(n)}$ but $x_{n+1}-x_n$ does not tend to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n>0$ be a sequence of real numbers such that 
$x_n \sim \frac n{\log(n)} =: y_n $ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Should we have that $x_{n+1}-x_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity? At least, if the limit exists, must it be $0$?
I noticed that $\lim_{n \to \infty } (y_{n+1}-y_n) = 0$. Must it be the case for $x_n$ also?

Comment: If you set $x_n =\lfloor y_n\rfloor$, then the limit of $x_{n+1}-x_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Take $x_n  = \frac{n}{\log(n)} + (-1)^n$.

Comment: @NarukiMasuda : Thank you. But I'm not sure to know why the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @guest : I think I see that the limit doesn't exist, thank you. But would you have an example where $x_{n+1}-x_n$ converges to a non-zero limit?

Comment: Because each of $x_n$ is an integer and $y_n$ tends to $\infty$ slower than $n$, the differences must be $0$ or $1$, and both appear infinitely many times.

Comment: No, this cannot happen.  If $x_{n+1}-x_n$ had a non-zero limit $l$, then for all $n>n_0$ $x_{n+1}-x_n>l/2$ so by summing from $n_0$ to $n$ we get $x_{n+1}>x_{n_0} + (n-n_0)l/2$ for all large $n$.

Comment: @NarukiMasuda : please make your comments into an answer :-)

Comment: I'd rather say that guest's answer is complete and I have nothing to write as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the original question, you can take $x_n = \frac{n}{\log{n}}+(-1)^n$ to get a counterexample.

For the question in the comments, $x_{n+1}-x_n$ cannot have a non-zero limit.  Such a limit would have to be positive (otherwise the sequence would be eventually decreasing, contradicting the asymptotic), say $l>0$.  Then for $n>n_0$, $x_{n+1}-x_n>l/2$ which by summing from $n_0$ to $n$ gives $$x_{n}>x_{n_0} + (n-n_0)l/2$$ again contradicting the asymptotic.